# Finding a good hash function for Rabin-Karp string search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash, rabin-karp

What are some good hash functions that can be used for implementing [Rabin-Karp string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm)? I only know of polynomial hash, but it has some flaws — most notably, if hashing is done modulo 2<sup>64</sup>, there is a test which is guaranteed to produce collisions very often (and using another modulus is impractical because the `mod` operation is very expensive). So, is there a **fast, easy-to-write** good hash function?

P.S. I know about buzhash, but I am wondering if there are other alternatives…

Comment: mod (%) is not expensive. It *used* to be expensive in the 1980's. Question: why should the hash function be *fast*?

Comment: BTW: modulo (1<<64) is certainly not expensive. If you use 64 bits *unsigned* types it is *tout gratuit*.

Comment: @wildplasser his comment about particular tests seem to imply this question is being asked from a programming competition standpoint, in which modulo 1<<64 is impractical: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4898

Comment: @ffao You’re right. In fact, I am asking *precisely* because of the post you’ve linked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's not a security hash and you just need a "good" fingerprint, I would suggest something like [Tabulation hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulation_hashing). The hole operation will be about multiple fold faster than mod operation.